# C# Clear button to se all my int to 0 and strings to " "

Tags: c#, string, int

I would like to make a button that sets all my int's and string's back to nothing (0 and "").

Example of string's and int's being used:

```
private void btn_H_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    H++;
    h = "H";
    txt_Chemical.Text = h + li + na + k + rb + cs + fr;

    if (H > 1)
    {
        h = "";
        h = "H" + H;
        //hm = hm * H;
        //string strhm = Convert.ToString(hm);
        // txt_Mass.Text = strhm + strlim;               
        txt_Chemical.Text = h + li + na + k + rb + cs + fr;
    }
}
```

What I tried to do:

```
private void btn_Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int H = 0;
    string h = "";

    int Li = 0;
    string li = "";

    txt_Chemical.Clear();
    txt_Mass.Clear();
}
```

Comment: In your example, you are re-declaring `H`, `h`, `Li`, and `li`. This means they are new [local] variables. So, when you assign to them, you are not assigning to the actual variables that you intend to clear. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks didn't know this yet fixes a lot of problems i have been working around!!!

Comment: Just remove the type names (`int` and `string`) in front of the variable names in `btn_Clear_Click` to use the existing variables (in fact class fields).